# How to check if the lua function is available in vim script?

Tags: vimscript, lua

On nvim, we can use 'v:lua' prefix to call a lua function in vim script. But can we check if the lua function is available, like `exists('*funcname')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty trivial.

```
function! IsLuaFunction(name) abort
    return luaeval(a:name)->type() == v:t_func
endfunction
```

As a note, some of Lua variables cannot be converted to VimL, and so the function potentially may throw an exception. If (unlikely) that's a problem then evaluate `type()` on Lua side instead.

Comment: Thanks. I found it works fine on nvim. But on vim9.0, the lua54.dll can not be loaded and E370 error happens on my Windows 10. Anyway, I will implement it to call v:lua.vim.diff()  on my plugin (https://github.com/rickhowe/diffchar.vim) soon, since the built-in function is so fast.